# Memory management ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I come from java background so I'm noob in memory management. Do I need to release memory from NSString *str = @"hi";? I do need to release NSString *str = [[NSString alloc init]? What about those UILabel that I synthesize?

Comment: Use ARC instead of manual management, it will solve all of these problems.

Comment: And try reading the documentation or searching here before posting. This has been done to death.

Comment: ...it's note a great question, but Richard - that's not a particularly helpful comment. Even with ARC it's very useful to understand how memory management on iOS works, and ARC doesn't 'solve' all the problems: it simply removes some and introduces some others.

Comment: Like others have said, ARC is not a silver bullet. You will not always be able to use it, and you should still know how memory management works without it.  As for your question, if you add an autorelease, the object will be released automatically when it returns to the main run loop.  This relieves you of your duty to manually call release

Answer (score 2):

The case `NSString *str = @"hi";` you don't have to release the string because it's a compile time constant string object (you are not the owner). In second case `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init]` you have to release it because you are owner, you are allocating the memory, so you are the responsible.

You have to release the synthesize properties if you declare the property like `retain` or `copy`. Usually a good site where release them is the `dealloc` method.

You should read this Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1). It's a litte large, but useful ;).

Comment: What about those UILabel that I synthesize?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do that now, with ARC memory management.  Check out [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) link for more information, or just search "ARC memory management" on Google.

If you still want to manually manage your memory, you can turn ARC off.  Check out [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-in-objective-c-tutorial) link for a quick memory management tutorial.

EDIT: If you are not using iOS 5, then you must manually manage memory. In response to your question "What about those UILabel that I synthesize," if you are asking how to release them you simply call

```
[label release];
```

It would be wise to call all release statements in

```
- (void)dealloc
```

For example:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [label release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: ARC is a compiler based memory management strategy. It is agnostic of the iOS you are deploying to, although I believe it does require the 4.0 or greater SDK.